# ASP.NET Core TextArea Not Rendering Value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a string that I'm trying to display as a default but editable value in a form. With input, using a Viewbag works perfectly. But with this part of the form, I need a textarea because it's a multiline entry.

```
<textarea asp-for="FivText" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.remark"></textarea>
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried this, on the server side:

```
PostFiv postFiv = new PostFiv { FivText = remark };
```

Coupled with this:

```
<textarea asp-for="FivText" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

I read somewhere the textarea overwrites your values on purpose. I may have read that in the wrong context though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content as inner html:

```
<textarea asp-for="FivText" class="form-control">
    @ViewBag.remark
</textarea>
```

Comment: "The name 'Viewbag' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @NickFleetwood , I used what you provided in your question, it can be anything else you use in the backend to bind the `remark` value.

Comment: No, I used ViewBag.remark and I got that error. Exactly what I posted. Let me play with it again. I actually came up with a weird workaround, but I'd rather do this.